# Google Translator Workflow

Tags: google-translate

Can some body tell me how a webpage content is sent to google translator and translated and shown again in the same webpage?I mean the complete work flow of the google website translator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google doesn't show the same web page.  Google shows a translated web page.  Take a closer look at the address bar of the translated web page.

The work flow goes like this.

- Read web page
- Process web page, translating text, while leaving the HTML in English.
- Write translated web page to disk, so it can be crawled later.
- Display web page from disk in a frame, with your GUI on the top frame.